# useState no actualiza un valor al recibirlo en useEffect en el navegador móvil

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

tengo el siguiente código hecho en next.js:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const foodsData = await getFoods();
      console.log(foodsData.foods);
      setFoods(foodsData.foods);
      setQuantities(foodsData.foods.map(() => 0));
      setCart(foodsData.foods.map((food) => ({ ...food, quantity: 0 })));
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Trae una serie de datos desde la base de datos, y se supone que actualiza los useState, pero pasa algo raro, acá:

```
const filteredCart = new Array(foods.length).fill(null);
  for (let i = 0; i < foods.length; i++) {
    if (quantities[i] > 0) {
      filteredCart[i] = cart[i];
    }
  }
```

Cuando corro este proyecto en el navegador de mi computadora funciona perfecto, y sin problemas, pero al hacerlo desde el navegador de mi celular, me da un error en foods.lenght y me dice que foods es undefined

¿Por qué en la computadora si obtiene los valores en el tiempo adecuado pero en el celular los consigue tan tarde y no funciona?

Comment: Ya hiciste esto?: [Publicación relacionada](https://dev.to/timreach/how-to-preview-a-nextjs-app-on-a-mobile-device-lf6)

Comment: claro, así es como estoy viendo la página en mi celular, pero da error